# MSCRM 2013 IPAD app throw following error "Error: This view is unavailable."

Tags: ipad, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

MSCRM 2013 IPAD app throw following error `"Error: This view is unavailable."` when I try to open activity link from left navigation. Can someone please help?

Comment: does the view exist in the browser client?  Is it a system view or personal view?  if its a personal view, do you have access to it?  if its a system view, do you have access to the entity?

Answer (score 0):

Personal views that are shared with you, are not available for mobile. It's anoying and I'm also looking for a workaround. For now, you can duplicate the shared view using Save As. Then you add that to a Dashboard you own. That will work.